# Creating SAS data set using multiple macro variables as values

Tags: macros, sas

I have several macro variables. For example,

```
%let var1 = GOOD;
%let var2 = BETTER;
%let var3 = BEST;
```

What I want to do is to create a data set using these macro variables like this

data set name: score
variable name:var

```
Obs   var
1     GOOD
2     BETTER
3     BEST
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
data want;
   format var $12.;

   var = "&var1";
   output;

   var="&var2";
   output;

   var="&var3";
   output;
run;

proc print data=want;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks! Can u simplify a little more?

Comment: how do you want it to be more simple?  Do you want something that is generic for N vars.  Usually you do not want to take values from Macros and put them into a data table.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a naming convention you can query the sashelp.vmacro table:

```
data _null_;
set sashelp.class;
call symput('name'||put(_n_, 2. -l), name);
run;

%put &name1.;
%put &name19.;

proc sql;
    create table want as
    select name, value
    from sashelp.vmacro
    where substr(name, 1, 4)='NAME';
quit;
```